# Reading a txt file line by line and treating each word

Tags: c, file

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char buffer[500];
    char tempstr[500];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    fp = fopen("aFaire.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, 500, (FILE*) fp)) {
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        while ((buffer[i]!='\n')&&(buffer[i]!='\0'))
        {
            if (buffer[i] !=' '){
                tempstr[j] = buffer[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else{
                tempstr[j]='\0';
                j=0;
                i++;
                printf("%s",tempstr);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }  
    fclose(fp);
}
```

What I am trying to do is to read a txt file line by line, then I treat each word in that line seperatly, first I read the line in buffer var, then copy each word in `tempstr`, the thing is `tempstr` is eating some words.

Comment: note that `'\n'` and `'\0'` must also be delimited.

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: You make space a word break(`if (buffer[i] !=' '){...}`), but you need to consider words that end with a newline(E.g `"word\n"`). (There may also be no newline) You are throwing away the contents of `tempstr` in such a case.

Comment: fix your approach like [this](https://ideone.com/3yHNzn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this more easily with `fscanf()`.

You need to get all the words from the input file and print them.

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)==1)
{
    printf("\n%s", buffer);
}
```

`fscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments. If it is not `1` here, the file is over or some error occurred.

On each iteration, a single word will be read into `buffer` which will then be displayed.

And make sure that `fopen()` really did open the file by ensuring that `fp` is not `NULL` like

```
if( (fp = fopen("aFaire.txt", "r"))==NULL)
{
    perror("\nUnable to open input file");
    return 1;
}
```

Edit:

In your program, the loop stops when the character is a `\n` or a (space). But the characters right before that may also form a word.

At the end of the `while` loop, add

```
tempstr[j]='\0';
printf("%s\n", tempstr);
```

Also, the line `i++;` appears in both the `if` and `else` parts inside the `while` loop. So instead of two `i++;`, a single one outside the `if`-`else` would suffice.

And inside the `else` part, the

```
printf("%s",tempstr);
printf("\n");
```

could be combined into

```
printf("%s\n",tempstr);
```

Like

```
while(fgets(buffer, 500, (FILE*) fp)) {
    i = j = 0;
    while ((buffer[i]!='\n')&&(buffer[i]!='\0'))
    {
        if (buffer[i] != ' '){
            tempstr[j] = buffer[i];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            tempstr[j]='\0';
            printf("%s\n",tempstr);
        }
        i++;
    }
    tempstr[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", tempstr);
}
```

In fact, I think a `for` loop would be more suited instead of the inner `while` loop.

```
while(fgets(buffer, 500, (FILE*) fp)) {
    for (i=j=0; (buffer[i]!='\n')&&(buffer[i]!='\0'); i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] != ' '){
            tempstr[j] = buffer[i];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            j=tempstr[j]='\0';
            printf("%s\n",tempstr);
        }
    }
    tempstr[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", tempstr);
}
```

Comment: this one worked fine, thanks, but can you still me why fgets failed?

Comment: @D.Mouttie I don't think `fgets()` failed in your code. The reason for the different output is probably because of the reasons that BLUEPIXY has pointed out.

Comment: ye, i fixed it, but i prefer your solution, it removes any extra space, so i don't have to right another function that does that

Comment: ye i like this solution, but fscanf does my job very well, i wanted to get every word in txt file and that's what it just does

Comment: @D.Mouttie I just added it anyway. :-)